# What is causing the "username_link not found" error in the LDAP integration module?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

After integration and configuration of the [LDAP integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap_integration) module, my site is unable to access the LDAP Server. During testing it throws below error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: username_link in theme_ldap_authorization_test_results() (line 91 of /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/ldap/ldap_authorization/ldap_authorization.theme.inc).

I am using Drupal - v7.44, and LDAP v 7.x-2.0-beta8 and the same LDAP server is working on other sites.

Is this a configuration issue or a bug?

Comment: As suggested by Pierre Vriens, Tried out the DB Config and got this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [comment nr 2 in issue nr 2751219](https://www.drupal.org/node/2751219#comment-11313249) this is not a bug, but it's just a configuration issue. Here is a quote from it:

> Incorrect admin password for LDAP server.

So double check the password is correct, and try again ...

Comment: Thanks Pierre, Yes I realized its an issue with connection to mysql DB. Thanks for support. I should mark this as solved.

Comment: @Umesh: About your "*I should mark this as solved*": if it was indeed the admin psw that was wrong, then maybe you want to "use" my answer to mark it like so?